# Failed to Lazily Load collection - Where to re-attach?

Tags: java, hibernate

So i am calling a List in an object whos fetch type is set to Lazy (intentional as onetomany, too many records etc)

I have a UI bean that is calling a Service method. I cannot reattach the object in the service as theres no general init method etc. Just wondering what approaches people have taken from within a service where you cant re-attach every time method is called (too often)

Exception only happens after List is accessed more thna once in a sequence.